# watch in PostgreSQL with clear screen (cos)

Tags: postgresql, watch

`\watch` command is great in Postrges.

It appends an output of a query, being watched over and over.

For example, when I previously run a query `SELECT id, nickname FROM users;`, and entered `\watch`, *in case of no new data*, I get the same output over and over:

```
my_db=# SELECT id, nickname FROM users;
 id | nickname 
----+----------
  1 | AntonAL
(1 row)

my_db=# \watch
четверг, 31 августа 2017 г. 13:23:26 (every 2s)

 id | nickname 
----+----------
  1 | AntonAL
(1 row)

четверг, 31 августа 2017 г. 13:23:28 (every 2s)

 id | nickname 
----+----------
  1 | AntonAL
(1 row)
```

It there any option **to clear screen output**, between watch executions?

I want to get dashboard-like experience, when a set of rows is displayed and refreshed, not appended over and over to the Postgres console output.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem, and with a suggestion from MatheusOl on `#postgresql`, the following works for me:

```
\C `clear`
SELECT * FROM pg_tables \watch 10
```

The [`\C [value]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) command sequence lets you set a title, and you can set that (shelling out with backticks) to the ANSI escapes returned by `clear`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `psql` has any way to clear the terminal. Maybe do with bash?

```
while true;
  clear;
  psql -c "SELECT id, nickname FROM users"
  sleep 2;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the last answer but a little simpler with the "watch" command (on linux) :

```
watch 'psql -c "SELECT id, nickname FROM users"'
```

... this will execute the query with psql every 2 seconds (default interval) and you can also add different parameters to this command :

```
$ watch --help

Usage:
 watch [options] command

Options:
  -b, --beep             beep if command has a non-zero exit
  -c, --color            interpret ANSI color and style sequences
  -d, --differences[=<permanent>]
                         highlight changes between updates
  -e, --errexit          exit if command has a non-zero exit
  -g, --chgexit          exit when output from command changes
  -n, --interval <secs>  seconds to wait between updates
  -p, --precise          attempt run command in precise intervals
  -t, --no-title         turn off header
  -x, --exec             pass command to exec instead of "sh -c"

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -v, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see watch(1).
```

I like to use this to monitor sessions activity with pg_stat_activity :

```
$ cat sessions.sql
select pid as process_id,
       usename as username,
       datname as database_name,
       client_addr as client_address,
       application_name,
       backend_start,
       state,
       state_change
from pg_stat_activity;

$ watch -d psql -f sessions.sql
```

... and we get this output refreshed every 2 seconds :

```
Every 2.0s: psql -f sessions.sql                                                                                                                                           Sun Sep 29 17:38:20 2019
 process_id | username | database_name | client_address | application_name |         backend_start         | state  |         state_change
------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------
       1240 | postgres |               |                |                  | 2019-09-29 15:40:36.697364-04 |        |
       1236 |          |               |                |                  | 2019-09-29 15:40:36.697681-04 |        |
      14025 | postgres | postgres      |                | psql             | 2019-09-29 17:38:20.508996-04 | active | 2019-09-29 17:38:20.511069-04
       1233 |          |               |                |                  | 2019-09-29 15:40:36.69497-04  |        |
       1232 |          |               |                |                  | 2019-09-29 15:40:36.695851-04 |        |
       1234 |          |               |                |                  | 2019-09-29 15:40:36.690183-04 |        |
(6 rows)
```